# Ellipsis with children div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html that is also bound to a bootstrap popover (if that makes any difference)

```
<div class="event" style="top: 0%; width: 100%;">
  <span class="test">Layouts</span>
  <div class="value">
    test
  </div>

  <span class="test">Starts</span>
  <div class="value">2014/12/12, 11:00</div>

  <span class="test">Ends</span>
  <div class="value">2015/1/16, 00:00</div>
</div>
```

with associated scss:

```
& > div.event {
        // position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        background-color: rgba(41, 128, 185,.7);
        outline: 1px solid rgba(155, 89, 182,1.0);
        min-height: 30px;
        color: white;
        // width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 1;

        font-size: 0.7em;
        .test {
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          float:left;
          // text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: 200;
          padding: 0;
        }

        .value {
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          float:left;
          color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
          margin-bottom: 5px;

          i.fa-external-link {
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: 23px;
          }
        }
        .value, .test {
          padding-right: 5px;
        }
```

My problem is that when I shrink the '.event' container (lets say to 5%) the text gets truncated and I would like to display it as ellipsis. From what I've read, the key is really to have overflow:hidden with white-space:nowrap as well as the text-overflow set. I juggled around, moving them to various elements, but nothing seems to work. I am doing something obviously wrong ? I can post more html and css if it appears that the problem lies at a higher level.

Fiddle to show problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/q1go1471/2/

Comment: Is that CSS or SCSS? It'd probably be faster to get an answer if you could reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle. (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you must specify a width for making `text-overflow: ellipsis` works.

Just modify this and it should work:

```
.value, .test {
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljo2eco9/

**EDIT:**

To create only 1 ellipsis in the end, use `display: inline;` instead of `float: left` in your children.

```
.test {
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 0;
}

.value {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.value, .test {
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljo2eco9/1/

Comment: Agreed, but that's not exactly what I want. I would like to have only 1 ellipsis at the end.